# How to close the activity from the service?

Tags: android

I am launching activity from the service based on some value got from the server and the activity will be displayed for the some time and after getting close instruction from the server i need to close that activity,so for that i used following approach but it's not working:
 on Service class:

```
if(((ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equals("com")) {

if(((ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName().equals("com.CustomDialogActivity")){
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CustomDialogActivity.class);
             dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);               
             dialogIntent.putExtra("description", "");
             dialogIntent.putExtra("cancelEnabled", false);
             dialogIntent.putExtra("close", true);
            getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);


}
    }
```

and on activity inside onCreate method:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean isClosed = bundle.getBoolean("close");
    if(isClosed){        
        finish();
 }
```

I debugged it and found that control reaches to the onCreate method if(isClosed) condition and executed finish() method also but its not closing the activity.

so Couldn't be able to analyze what wrong I am doing.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was not aware about it, going forward i will accept it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Write a broadcast receiver in your CustomDialogActivity like following.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver abcd = new BroadcastReceiver() {
             @Override
             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                   finish();                                   
             }
     };
```

Then register it in the same file like the following:

```
onCreate(){

    registerReceiver(abcd, new IntentFilter("xyz"));
}
```

Unregister it in onDestroy.

```
onDestroy(){

   //unRegister
}
```

Now,Whenever you want to close that Activity just call like the following.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("xyz"));
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi Jai,Thanks for ur reply, i tried that but still its not working.

Comment: it should work.Check whether onReceive() is calling or not.Did you register the receiver in onCreate?

Comment: onReceive() is not getting called, yeah i have registered the receiver in onCreate().

Comment: I have created IntentFilter in onCreate() with action "closeDialog" and registered it, unregistering I am doing in onDestroy() and calling sendBroadcast() in my service with Intent which is having same action "closeDialog". but still call is not coming to onReceive() method of receiver.So not sure what i am doing wrong.may be in this scenario it will not work,scenario is something like this: launched one activity as dialog when server sends response for launching it, now dialog is launched, after some time server again sends one response to the service for close the launched dialog.

Comment: HI,Does anyone is having any clue how to close the activity from the service? because above given answer is also not working.????

Comment: As StephaneB said: You must add the receiver into the manifest for your activity.

Comment: Don't forget to unregister the receiver in the onDestroy.

Comment: If the service and the activity are in the same application, I would recommend to use a LocalBroadcastManager. This has several advantages.  1- Other apps can't see the broadcast, and your app can't receive a broadcast from other apps.  2- You don't need to add the receiver in the manifest.  3-  It has better performance (see  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Comment: No need to add receiver to the manifest! 1) check when you register and unregister manifest. 2) check intent filters, they must be same when registering receiver and sending broadcast (in this case "xyz")

Answer (score 5):

You must add the receiver into the manifest for your activity, For example :

```
    <activity  android:name="MyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="xyz" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Does it mean that when `xyz` is received , the `MyActivity` will run ?

Comment: actually it means that the receiving activity fill be stopped, hence the finish() methos is called ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to send broadcast using context.

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("xyz"));
```

Answer from Jainal is Working for me.