# How to terminate Android app from within service?

Tags: android

On receiving a certain event in my Android service, I want to terminate the app from within the service. I know I can call `finish` in an activity to end it.

Also I understand that service will call `stopSelf()` on itself to end itself. But I need to terminate the entire app including any particular activity of the app that was visible at that time.

Any ideas?

Comment: check- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149501/how-to-close-the-activity-from-the-service

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());

Answer (score 0):

You can create an BaseActivity with BroadcastReceiver to close all Activities by registering it in `onCreate()` of BaseActivity and extending all your Activities with BaseActivity.

```
public static final String EXIT_APP_ACTION = "EXIT_APP_ACTION";

BroadcastReceiver ExitAppBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    finish();
    }
};
```

Register it in `onCreate()` for the BaseActivity in your Application using,

```
registerReceiver(ExitAppBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(EXIT_APP_ACTION));
```

Then you can fire this BroadcastReceiver from your Service using the Context to close all Activites including Service by calling `stofSelf()`,

```
stopSelf()
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(BaseActivity.EXIT_APP_ACTION));
```