# How to close activity Theme.dialog from service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-alertdialog

Basically I am creating dialog windows from background service in loop, meaning multiple dialog instances will get created.

**Like this:**

```
for(int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++){

    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

**In AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
     android:name=".DialogActivity"
     android:label="Alert Dialog"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
</activity>
```

Using this code, as service runs periodically it again creates dialogs over and over, creating a stack of dialog boxes.

**What I want is to close/dismiss these already created dialogs before creating new ones, from background service but not able to.**

Comment: Try to close multiple instances at once using dismiss method of activity with dialog "Theme".

Comment: have you tried calling `finish()` before creating new intent ?

Comment: @MyGod Tried to, not didn't found a way to do this.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori There is a need to show particular number of dialog boxes and to close all at once after some time, in a service.

Comment: Did you try flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP?

Comment: keep a static list of DialogActivities in DialogActivity class and add every new activity instance to it

Comment: Have you tried intent.putExtra("Id", id) and close those by id that is smaller than current anchor id onResume()?

Comment: @degrigorash Don't you think it will close all the other activities as well?

Comment: @mangusta The number of instances of DialogActivities is not fix, so cann't keep those in static way.

Comment: @IsabelHM How to get instance of DialogActivity using "id" ?

Comment: @RaviSharma what do you mean by "can't keep in static way" ? you simply add them into list, and then apply `finish()` on them `list.size()` times, when you need to close them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DialogActivity implement BroadcastReceiver according to this link:

[How to close the activity from the service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149501/how-to-close-the-activity-from-the-service)

So in your case before looping you should call

sendBroadcast(new Intent("xyz"));

which should close all activities created in previous loop.

Comment: Tried to follow as you suggested but this way number of dialogs opened is less than the expected number, suppose the number of expected dialogs is 5 but now these are in inconsistent manner, i.e. sometimes 3, sometimes 2...

Comment: You should call sendBroadcast(new Intent("xyz")); only once so it is irrelevant how many dialog are opened. All of them implement BroadcastReceiver should be closed once you broadcast intent with specific id(xyz)