# how to close previous activity from current activiy in android

Tags: android, android-service

Hi i am working with IME in android. In my keyboard i have a special key which start quick-Action with three option. Each option start a new activity. So here each activity is started from input method service. lets assume, Option 1 start activity 1, Option 2 start activity 2 So now activity 2 is foreground and 1 is background. I wanted activity 1 finish/destroy when activity 2/3 started or 2 is destroyed when 1/3 started and so on.
i search any only found

```
this.finish();
```

but this is only helpful when activity 1/2/3 started from another activity.How can i do this in service?thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close the activity from the service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149501/how-to-close-the-activity-from-the-service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain it's the best user experience, but you can usually accomplish that behavior with intent flags. In particular, adding [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) to the launch intents for your option activities will cause them to finish automatically when they are no longer in the foreground.